# Как удалить запись при связи many to many с составным ключем?

Tags: spring, hibernate

Всем привет!

Похоже я намудрил в реализации, что не получается удалить запись.

Кейс словами:
Есть сущности *Листы*, *Операции*, *Коды Дефектов*. *Листы* и *операции* образуют связную таблицу *Завершенные операции* с экстра колонкой сколько изделий пришло. *Завершенные операции* и *Коды Дефектов* образую связную таблицу *Дефекты на завершенных операциях* с колонкой количества бракованных изделий по кодам дефектов.

Выглядят сущности так:
Листы:

```java
@Entity
public class Sheet {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Microchip microchip;

    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne
    private Execution execution;

    @NotBlank
    private String crystal;

    @NotBlank
    private String sewing;

    @NotBlank
    private String productBody;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sheet", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<SheetPassedOperation> sheetPassedOperations;

    @Lob
    private String comment = "";
}
```

Операции:

```java
@Entity
public class Operation {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @NotBlank
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "operation")
    private Set<SheetPassedOperation> sheetPassedOperations;
}
```

Коды дефектов:

```java
@Entity
public class DefectCode {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column(unique = true)
    @NotBlank
    private String code;
    @NotBlank
    private String name;
}
```

Завершенные операции:

```java
@Entity
public class SheetPassedOperation {
    @EmbeddedId
    private SheetPassedOperationId id;
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("sheetId")
    private Sheet sheet;
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("operationId")
    private Operation operation;
    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime startedAt;
    @NotNull
    @DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE_TIME)
    private LocalDateTime finishedAt;
    @NotNull
    @Min(0)
    private Integer income;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "sheetPassedOperation", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<DefectPassedOperation> defects;
}
```

Дефекты на операциях:

```java
@Entity
public class DefectPassedOperation {
    @EmbeddedId
    private DefectPassedOperationId id;
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("sheetId")
    private Sheet sheet;
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("operationId")
    private Operation operation;
    @ManyToOne
    @MapsId("defectCodeId")
    private DefectCode defectCode;
    @NotNull
    @Min(1)
    private Integer quantity;
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumns({
            @JoinColumn(name = "sheet_id", referencedColumnName = "sheet_id", insertable = false, updatable = false),
            @JoinColumn(name = "operation_id", referencedColumnName = "operation_id", insertable = false, updatable = false)
    })
    private SheetPassedOperation sheetPassedOperation;
}
```

У меня не получается удалить DefectPassedOperation в контроллере, пробовал делать его репозиторий и через него удалять. Есть репозиторий SheetPassedOperation, но удаление в коллекции дефекта и сохранение образца класса не дало удаление из базы дефекта. В логе хибернета нет вызова удаления.

Так же пробовал сделать сервис с использованием транзакции, но не помогло.

Похоже чего-то не знаю в тонкости работы хибернета. Прошу подсказки знатоков

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Была проблема в связи из-за свойства

```java
cascade = CascadeType.ALL
```

поменял на

```java
cascade = CascadeType.REMOVE
```

и убрал у сущности листа.

```java
orphanRemoval = true
```

Так же из-за исправлений поправил добавление и редактирование новых элементов